# Why "do ... while (0)" can't be replaced by simple curly brackets?

Tags: c, scope, macros, curly-braces

I recently saw a piece of C code including a macro of the following style:

```
#define TOTO()              \
do {                        \
  do_something();           \
  do_another_something();   \
} while (0)
```

I was at first wondering of the purpose of the `do while (0)` here, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/154138/4745527) explained to me: it is in case the macro is used just after an `if` or `else` without curly brackets, like this:

```
if (something)
    TOTO();
else
    do_something_else();
```

So here, without the `do while (0)` statement, the code would be expanded to:

```
if (something)
    do_something();
    do_another_something();
else
    do_something_else();
```

Which is syntactically wrong, because the `else` is not directly following an `if` scope anymore.

But I thought it would work as well by declaring the macro in its own scope, without necessary a `do while` around it, so I tested the same code with just curly brackets. My entire code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define HELLO_WORLD()       \
{                           \
    printf("hello ");       \
    printf("world!\n");     \
}

int     main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc == 1)
        HELLO_WORLD();
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "nope\n");
    return 0;
}
```

But GCC give me the following error:

> error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’

However, the code of the `main` function should be expanded to:

```
if (argc == 1)
    {
        printf("hello ");
        printf("world!\n");
    }
else
    fprintf(stderr, "nope\n");
return 0;
```

Which is valid.

So what am I missing here?

Comment: The semicolon you have put after `HELLO_WORLD()`

Comment: As always when facing macro-related problems: your compiler may have a switch to output the preprocessed file, so you can see what the actual input to the code compiler looks like.

Comment: @Downvoters How is this a bad question? It is a duplicate, yes, but then mark it as one at least instead of downvoting and telling everybody it's a bad question. Or what's the reason for this?

Comment: The first part `do{} while()` part has nothing to do with the his code I think . ( However I didn't downvote I just think about the reason )

Comment: The whole do-while-zero macro trick was always kind of retarded, because it assumes that code without braces is good and should be used. The proper solution is to adopt a coding standard which always enforces braces after each and every statement, and then check the code with static analysis to ensure that it does.

Comment: For that reason the  `{ }` macro is **better** practice than `do {} while(0)`, because it creates a compiler error if you don't have any braces in the caller.

Comment: @Aracthor No! `if(something) { { stuff(); } ; } else` is perfectly fine C code, as opposed to `if(something) { stuff(); } ; else`.  Where `{ stuff(); }` is your expanded macro.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the semicolon after the macro.

The macro is expanded to this instead:

```
if (argc == 1)
    {
        printf("hello ");       \
        printf("world!\n");     \
    };
else        // HERE, SYNTAX ERROR
    fprintf(stderr, "nope\n");
return 0;
```

Since there should be no semicolon between the body of an `if`-statement and an `else`-clause, it's a syntax error.
OTOH, a `do`-`while` loop allows (and needs) a semicolon.

---

The misconception regarding the compiler output can be easily avoided by just printing the real preprocessor output. That's possible by using

- the `-E` switch of the `gcc` executable. From [`man 1 gcc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html):

> **-E** Stop after the preprocessing stage; do not run the compiler
>              proper.  The output is in the form of preprocessed source code,
>              which is sent to the standard output.

- the preprocessor directly in shape of the [`cpp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cpp) executable.

---

<sub>Thanks to

- @dhke for correcting the line the error occurs at.

- @kakeh for the suggestion to view the preprocessor output beforehand.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Look CAREFULLY at how you call the macro.

You'd have to write

```
if (argc == 1)
    HELLO_WORLD() // NO SEMICOLON!!!!!!!
else
    fprintf(stderr, "nope\n");
```

which would be godawful because you could never replace the HELLO_WORLD macro with a real function.